# How do I separate multiple numerical data values in a cell & find total of each column?

Tags: r

I have two numeric data values in one cell and I want to separate them to find the total and percentage of each column.

Such as:

| Organization | Media |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1,2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

We could try

```
lapply(df1,  function(x) proportions(table(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ","))))))
```

or may be

```
lapply(df1,  function(x) addmargins(table(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ","))))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Organization = c("1,2", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1", 
"1"), Media = c("1", "1,2", "3", "1,4", "4", "1", "2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```